# Pattern matching for case classes derived from same trait

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

everyone!

I have a little problem with Scala pattern matching. I am using [Korolev](https://github.com/fomkin/korolev) framework for my web application, but I bet  problem is deeper in Scala as is.

I have a base trait for all states:

```
trait BaseState {
  val notifications: List[Notification]
}
```

And two derived case classes:

```
case class GuestState(
                       notifications: List[Notification] = List(),
                       isRegistration: Boolean = false
                     ) extends BaseState
```

and

```
case class AuthenticatedState(
                          notifications: List[Notification] = List(),
                          user: UserWithPermissions
                        ) extends BaseState
```

In one of event handlers I need to get similar state without certain notification. For now it works like that:

```
event('click) { access =>
              access.transition {
                case s: GuestState => s.copy(notifications = notifications.filter(x => x != n))
                case s: AuthenticatedState => s.copy(notifications = notifications.filter(x => x != n))
              }
          }
```

For both types I have to do absolutely same thing with duplicating of code because `BaseState` does not have `copy()` method and compiler fails with error.

How can I do it properly in scala-way? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The two cases do not actually do the same thing, because the two `copy` methods have different signatures. So while it may be textually the same, the code is actually doing something different in each case.

One option here is to add an abstract `filterNotifications` method to the trait and call that:

```
trait BaseState {
  val notifications: List[Notification]
  def filterNotifications(f: Notification => Boolean): BaseState
}

case class GuestState(
  notifications: List[Notification] = List(),
  isRegistration: Boolean = false
) extends BaseState {
  def filterNotifications(f: Notification => Boolean): BaseState =
    this.copy(notifications=notifications.filter(f))
}

case class AuthenticatedState(
  notifications: List[Notification] = List(),
  user: UserWithPermissions
) extends BaseState {
  def filterNotifications(f: Notification => Boolean): BaseState =
    this.copy(notifications=notifications.filter(f))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar scenarios in the past and never found a really elegant solution to this, as copy methods with identical or similar signatures cannot be easily expressed in a polymorphic way.

I usually added some plumbing to the trait and case classes so that the repetition is at least in one place:

```
trait BaseState {
  type ThisType <: BaseState
  val notifications: List[Notification]
  def withNotifications(notifications: List[Notification]): ThisType
}

case class GuestState(notifications: List[Notification] = List(),
                    isRegistration: Boolean = false) extends BaseState {
  type ThisType = GuestState
  def withNotifications(notifications: List[Notification]): ThisType = 
    copy(notifications = notifications)
}

case class AuthenticatedState(notifications: List[Notification] = List(),
                            user: UserWithPermissions) extends BaseState {
  type ThisType = AuthenticatedState
  def withNotifications(notifications: List[Notification]): ThisType = 
    copy(notifications = notifications)
}
```

This is quite far from ideal though, and maybe there are better patterns.
But if you use logic like in your example a lot, it would at least reduce the boilerplate significantly. If the filter logic is also repeatedly used, you could add a more concrete `filterNotififications` to the base trait.

The advantage of this solution compared to the other answer is that you do not lose type precision when filtering.

And remember to seal the trait wherever possible.

Answer (score 2):

It is not solvable without changing base trait. Compiler cannot allow you to perform operation `copy` on trait when it clearly does not have it.

One approach is to specify mapping/filtering function on BaseState as other answers suggest.

Another approach is to replace inheritance with composition:

```
case class Notified(state: BaseState, notifications: List[Notification] = List())

sealed trait BaseState
case class GuestState(isRegistration: Boolean = false) extends BaseState 
case class AuthenticatedState(user: UserWithPermissions) extends BaseState

val notified = Notified(GuestState())
val result = notified.copy(notifications = notifications.filter(_ => true))
```